# How do you loop though all members of a guild in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

To get all the members in a server ( guild ) i use `guild.members`. But i want to loop through all of the members. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you've got the right idea.

```py
for m in guild.members:
    # do something
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members)

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you, as if other people are having the same issue, it'll help then find the answer! Good luck with the bot :)